# How to fix this simple Foreign Key error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

How must I do this query? About a simple foreign key query

This is for a little project that I am doing

For example with these players:

players:

```
| PlayerId | name | team_TeamId |

| 1        | john | 1           |
| 2        | myke | 1           |
| 3        | carl | 2           |
```

And this teams:

team:

```
| TeamId | name        |

| 1      | Arsenal     |
| 2      | Real Madrid |
```

```sql
SELECT player.name, team.name
FROM player, team
WHERE player.team_TeamId = 1
```

This query shows me this:

```
| name | team.name   |

| john | Arsenal     |
| myke | Arsenal     |
| john | Real Madrid |
| myke | Real Madrid |
```

It "works" with this query(obviusly is not the correct form):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM player, team
WHERE player.team_TeamId = 1 AND team.TeamId = 1
```

```
| name | team.name   |

| john | Arsenal     |
| myke | Real Madrid |
```

I expected only players with teamId = 1, but the actual output is players with teamId = 1 but repeats with ALL teams.

Comment: Please add sample table data along with the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I probably don't know the correct answer. What I am seeing from my end, there is no relation in the way that you are trying to select. But you can have a solution by adding two virtual column in both table.

```
select pt.name,tt.name from (SELECT player.*, @i:=@i+1  AS rowNum 
 FROM player , (SELECT @i:=0) AS temp
WHERE player.team_TeamId = 1) as pt LEFT JOIN
(SELECT team.*, @j:=@j+1  AS rowNum  from team  , (SELECT @j:=0) AS temp ) as tt  on 
pt.rowNum = tt.rowNum
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM player
JOIN team ON player.team_TeamId = team.TeamId
WHERE team.TeamId = 1
```

Comment: can you elaborate and explain your answer? BTW you are just switching from implicit to explicit join.